# failed to run a MySQL file using a batch file in windows

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file

I am trying to run `MySQL` files from a `batch` file .

I am currently using this code

```
mysql -u<root> -p<> -e "source C:/xampp/htdocs/internet_wk_1.7/db/master_db.sql" kani
```

- `root` is my user name.
- I have no password.
- I want to run the `master_db.sql`, the path is correct.
- the database name is `kani`, it already exists

When I run the `batch` file nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

hi i solved it . this my new code

```
CLS
C:
cd\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql -u root -e "source C:\xampp\htdocs\internet_wk_1.7\db\master_db.sql" kani
```

but i have more than one sql file in my folder , i want run them too. i tried like this but not working  , please help

```
CLS
C:
cd\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql -u root -e "source C:\xampp\htdocs\internet_wk_1.7\db\master_db.sql" kani
source C:\xampp\htdocs\internet_wk_1.7\db\master_db_tracker.sql
```

Comment: Are you really passing the `<`, `>` characters to the mysql command? If yes, remove them.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name , hi i updated my question , please take a look

Answer (score 1):

```
CLS
C:
cd\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql -u root -e "source C:\xampp\htdocs\internet_wk_1.7\db\master_db.sql" kani
mysql -u root -e "source C:\xampp\htdocs\internet_wk_1.7\db\master_db_tracker.sql" kani
```